# How to start game programming without a graphic artist?

Tags: android, graphics

Having a hard time phrasing the question, my situation actually is on the release phase of the game development cycle.

I have this game that falls under the casual category with little to no-complex-logic involved at all, running on a 2D side scrolling (semi) single character. In short it really is simple, so I am already done with the code and just need to replace sprites with my own to avoid any copyright issues once I decide to release it on the market (truth is I used sprites from various forums of another side scrolling MMORPG).

So my actual problem is, being an independent developer, with no talent in graphic arts and little budget to outsource a graphic artist, How would I (a plain programmer) create a modern looking graphical game?

Note:

1. The game is non-profit, I made it just to learn what the android platform has to offer.
   But seeing it can actually be fun for others to play with, I'd like to release it.
2. I wanted to make this a community wiki as I see other game programming beginners would also face the same question. Although I am not that sure if that reason alone qualifies. But it seems with my reputation now, I'd leave that to the admin / mods decisions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming

Answer (score 1):

Keep the resources seperate and replace them before releasing with free versions or your own art.

There is no cheap source of high quality (graphics) unless you find someone willing to work for you cheap or for free.

Be very careful with copying sprites from other games. Some publishers have (and keep) very strict policies.

Another forum/site that might give you more information is http://www.Gamedev.net

Especially interesting might be [the resources found here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/544073-free-2d3d-art-assets-09/)

Comment: i believe i am aware of that and that is the reason why i intend to replace their sprites with something i can call my own before releasing the game in public.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is on Android but whenever I've tried games for fun, I've always relied on free sprite sheets which are all over the net. I've also clipped off a few from old DOS games which I run via. dosbox.

Comment: err that's exactly what i did, i actually used sprites from maple story :P

Comment: It shouldn't be much of a problem then for a "trial/training" app. The sprites are usually swappable. Once you've reached professional quality and want to actually sell the game, you can consider hunting for an artist or doing some sprites yourself.

Comment: hmmm i think the question is misleading, im not actually starting the game development, rather ending it and im on the process of just replacing the sprites for release. So the question really is seeking advise on how can programmers produce quality graphics if budget is limited? anyway i'll try to update the question to better reflect the actual situation i am on.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite tactic is to put ugly placeholder graphics inside the game, and brag with it to my fellow pixel-movers.  Next, someone from the pool will be disgusted with my lack of taste and ability to do good graphics, and put himself into the game.

If it doesn't work, you can always go headhunting, having your game ready and with just graphics to replace.

Answer (score 0):

I stayed on the same problem, like you did.
Me as programmer also wanted to start coding a little android game, because i never did before.
And my garphic/artist skill is like  3-year-old-child...

So i tried to think of a designconcept with very easy geometrical Forms, if you are not so skilled.
And with the open source Software gimp you can do alot.

I dont know which engine you use, but i decided for unity3d, cause you are very flexible and you also can cross compile your project. I dont had experience with c#, but its very easy if you came from other oop languages, like java, so maybe have look for it. :)

Maybe also look what i made of it, it were just some circles and lines! 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.duckdev.anbr 
greets